# Returning the selected cell value from table view controller on back button press

Tags: ios

I have 2 table view controllers where I on button click on first controller, I am pushing to another view controller.

On the second table view controller, I have a list of items which is checkmarked upon selection. I want to return the selected value to the first view controller.

Also, please let me know how can I use that value in first view controller.

I cant use seagues and the second view controller is generic so I cannot set any of the variables of first view controller in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a delegate for that second view controller

In the .h you could declare

```
@protocol SecondControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)selectionDidFinish:(NSArray*)objects;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<SecondControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Then in your .m in view will disappear :

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.delegate selectionDidFinish:yourArray];
}
```

And in your first view controller you'd have to implement this protocol :

in .h :

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <SecondControllerDelegate>
```

and in .m

```
- (void)selectionDidFinish:(NSArray*)objects{
    //Do whatever you want with selected objects
}
```

and of course when you create your second view controller you'd have to do :

```
SecondViewController *sVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
sVC.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to create a mutable object (NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary) in the parent controller and pass it to the child, so the child can modify it and when you are back to the parent - the mutable object will contain the modified values.

Another approach, which requires a little more knowledge is to use a protocol. The basic idea is to create a protocol and a delegate, so the child can "notify" the parent that it chose some values. You can check these examples:
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/15/passing-data-between-views-tutorial-using-a-protocol-delegate-in-your-iphone-app/

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Please tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can create delegates. Checkout the following link:
http://www.hardcodedstudios.com/home/ryan-newsome/simpledelegatetutorialforiosdevelopment